# Input/output error reading file

Tags: linux, centos-6

I have a file that is 6.6GB, it just so happens to be a video file, and I'm trying to copy it to an external drive since its quite important for me to keep, however when I try copying it whether with nautilus or dd or whatever it fails at 1GB saying that htere is an input/output error. However when I view it with VLC I can watch the whole thing just fine so I know that the content is there and it works but I can't seem to copy it over...

Does anyone have any way that I can copy over?

I am running Centos 6.3.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the usual DVD copy-protection thing. When a DVD player finds an unreadable sector it should skip over it - but computers behave differently and try to recover the data - hence this is commonly used as a method of preventing DVD ripping - but it's relatively trivial to work around. VLC and mplayer happily cope with it. With mplayer you can write the stream to a file, e.g.

```
 mplayer -dvd-device /dev/sr0 dvd://1 -dumpstream -dumpfile ~/video
```

IIRC VLC has similar (a quick google [turned up this](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2696/how-to-rip-dvds-with-vlc/) and many other links - although most refer to MSWindows, the process is the same). There's also [dvdbackup](http://dvdbackup.sourceforge.net/) - a simple command line tool.